# Is it possible to create "fake" file like unix socket and which allows write with `echo`?

Tags: ruby, file, sockets

Is is possible (in Ruby or in general) to create some kind of blackhole file like socket. But to allow write as to regular file `echo "newline" >> my-fake-file`.

I tried unix socket, but it fails to write into it. I don't care about reading it, because all  would be processed by running daemon. Best would be not to write into it at all.

Why I need it? I need to process logs written to file. And nginx allows only file logs (without patch).

Comment: @Jordan, my understanding is that Michal needs to process the data that is written, but only in memory. As Joni says, POSIX's mkfifo will set this pipe up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To throw the data away completely, write to **/dev/null**.

To pass the data to another process you can use a **named pipe**. A named pipe is a special file that can be used for inter-process communication: data written by one process is read by another. See `man mkfifo`.

Comment: Thats what I want. Just hope that it wont blonk nginx logging.

Comment: As long as the fifo is read as fast as than nginx writes there should be no problem.